# WPF Telerik UI BusyIndicator not showing (UI Thread) using MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, telerik, busyindicator

I am struggling to get the following solution to work:

**C# - Properties**

```
 // IsBusy 
private bool _IsBusy;
public bool IsBusy
{
    get
    {
        return _IsBusy;
    }
    set
    {
        _IsBusy = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsBusy");
    }
}

// IsHidden
private bool _IsHidden;
public bool IsHidden
{
    get
    {
        return _IsHidden;
    }
    set
    {
        _IsHidden = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsHidden");
    }
}
```

**C# - MainViewModel (Command action)**

```
private void OpenManagerConsole()
{
    try
    {
        ShowLoader();

        Frame OpenScreen = new Frame();
        OpenScreen = homewindow.FindName("Main") as Frame;
        OpenScreen.Content = new ManagerConsole();
        OpenScreenName = "Manager Console";

        HideLoader();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

**C# - MainViewModel (ShowLoader() method)**

```
private void ShowLoader()
{
    try
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        IsHidden = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

**XAML - MainView**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
    <Frame x:Name="Main" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Margin="0" BorderBrush="Transparent"/>
</Grid>


<telerik:RadBusyIndicator Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                          telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8Touch" d:IsHidden="{Binding IsHidden, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Currently when I launch my application it loads the MainView with a nested element called **Main** which is Frame. This frame is used to display the content of the different pages of the application. When I try to navigate to a screen called **Manager Console** it doesn't show the busy indicator and just stalls the UI until the **managerconsole content** is loaded. I know that his has to do with the UI thread. I have tried to use a background worker for the **ShowLoader();** but just can't seem to find the right way to apply the background worker to get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show how your properties are defined and how you implemented your MainViewModel?

Comment: You set IsHidden to _true_ in _Show_Loader. Without knowing the Telerik Controls this seems counter intuitive to me. I'd assume you'd have to set "IsHidden" to false. I am assuming your ViewModel raises PropertyChangedEvent correctly.

Comment: P.S.: You surround the setting of boolean Properties in try/catch. Why? What could possibly throw an exception there?

Comment: Not that `throw ex;` would make more sense :)

Comment: It was just a copied body content, from another method. At this point in time I just want to get it to work. @Fildor  that might be the issue that I've overseen.

Comment: Another point: IsHidden and IsBusy are bound "TwoWay" - this seems also unnecessary to me. Although it shouldn't have an effect on the perceived behavior.

Comment: @Fildor yes it does seem unnecessary, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to relieve your GUI thread from the work between ShowLoad() and HideLoader(). Try to use a task for the resource heavy parts of the code:

**Example (untested):**

```
private void OpenManagerConsole()
{
    try
    {
        ShowLoader();

        Frame OpenScreen = new Frame();
        OpenScreen = homewindow.FindName("Main") as Frame;
        OpenScreenName = "Manager Console";

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            return new ManagerConsole();
        }).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            OpenScreen.Content = t.Result;              
            HideLoader();
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());    
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Also, you don't have to set

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

in your xaml for the Busy Indication to update.

Comment: It only shows the loader and changes the Screen name but doesn't load the frame content...

Comment: Did you try to debug and check what is happening?

Comment: Yes and when it reaches "OpenScreen.Content = t.Result", it throws the following: "Task.cs not found, you need to find task.cs to view the source for the current call stack frame".